# Writing before specific line python

Tags: python, file

i have this piece of code:

```
asm = open(infile)
asmw = open(outfile, "w")
shutil.copyfile(infile, outfile)
for x in range(0, 8):
    xorreg.append("xor " +  reg[x] + ", " +  reg[x])
for line in asm:
    if any(s in line for s in xorreg):
    found += line.count(xorreg[x])
    print line
```

i want to write some text lines in the file right before "line" (the one printed) 
how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: `print "something else"` ?

Comment: i mean, write in the file

Comment: but that way the line that i wanna write would be after the one i looked for, no?

Comment: I'll post an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script appends to every lien containing the string `Gandalf` a new string `The greatest wizard of all times was:`

```
# show what's in the file
with open("some_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    print f.read()

new_content = []
with open("some_file.txt", "r") as asmr:
    for line in asmr.readlines():
        if "Gandalf" in line:
            # we have a match,we want something but we before that...
            new_content += "The greatest wizard of all times was:"
        new_content += line

# write the file with the new content
with open("some_file.txt", "w") as asmw:
    asmw.writelines(new_content)

# show what's in the file now
with open("some_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

Comment: thanks for that. the problem is that i dont wanna show the file, im showing only the lines that contains some element of my xorreg[] array. and these elements are the ones that i want to write before

Comment: What do you mean by `show`? You don't have to show the file, this was just for anyone reading this to be clearer. You only need to re write the file, and when you encounter a row you want to add a line before, you need to add the new line and only than the original line.